# Sequelize double relationships

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm doing a node.js project that allows virtual trading between user.

A User can have many trades. Each Trade will have to contain 2 fk from User, which are the id of the seller as well as the buyer.
[image]

I'm using sequelize in node.js to build up the model.

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
import {sequelize} from '../database/connection.js';

const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    id:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
}, {
    // Other model options go here
    sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
    freezeTableName: true
});

module.exports = User
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

```
// Trade 
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize');
import {sequelize} from '../database/connection.js';

const Trade = sequelize.define('Trade', {
  // Model attributes are defined here
    id:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    isPaid:{
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    }
    // fk are in relationships.js
  }, {
  // Other model options go here
  sequelize, // We need to pass the connection instance
  freezeTableName: true
});

module.exports = Trade
```

/////////////////////////////////////

```
//relationships

User.hasMany(Trade,{
    foreignKey: "offererId"
})
Trade.belongsTo(User);

//
User.hasMany(Trade,{
    foreignKey: "receiverId"
})
Trade.belongsTo(User);
```

Is this a right solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [super M:N](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html) may be your most versatile option.

```
User.belongsToMany(User, { through: Trade, as: "offerer", foreignKey: "offererId"})
User.belongsToMany(User, { through: Trade, as: "receiver", foreignKey: "receiverId"})
Trade.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(Trade)
```

This allows you to use the auto-generated association methods and query user on user.